# Java - Permission issue when writing to a file Ubuntu

Tags: java, ubuntu, permissions

I am trying to write to a file using a FileOutputStream in java. I am running ubuntu and I think the problem is with the permissions. Even though the error I receive says '(No such file or directory)' I am sure the path I am giving is right, since I can read from the same file with no issues. I am not very familiar with ubuntu write permissions but I think I need to set the mode with chmod -r on the root directory. However I am not sure of the exact command and the option of permission I should set.

Comment: Where is the file is located exactly? The exact path? You can use 'ls -l' to use permissions on the file. Maybe you should move the file into your home directory instead of doing things in root(if that is not exactly required).

Comment: Don't change permissions on the whole root directory! Either do as selim suggests and put it in your home directory or just modify the concerned file using chmod a+w <file> or chown <user> <file>. Prepend sudo if ubuntu complains, e.g. sudo chown <user> <file>